# ios dispatch_once crash with signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get crash with GCD once point at

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static TabBarViewController *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
        DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block){
    if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block); <-Crash:Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    } else {
        dispatch_compiler_barrier();
    }
    DISPATCH_COMPILER_CAN_ASSUME(*predicate == ~0l);
}
```

strangely is that some code sometimes crash and after a few time it works well. 
I have no idea why......

Comment: Can you please add crash report so that we can get idea where actually its crashing your app ?

Comment: From the source code posted so far, I cannot see any error. Please post a backtrace. Maybe the problem is in `init` of your `TabBarViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

have same issue, wrap `dispatch_one {}` in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() ...` so it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was in calling [... sharedInstance] twice at almost the same time so it enters dispatch_once block second time before first one is finished.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with TabBarViewController. Its singleton method may be called again in the init method. or it is held by another singleton and the singleton holding it is called right in the init method.

```
// implementation ClassA
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static ClassA *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [ClassB sharedInstance]; 
    }
    return self;
}

// implementation ClassB
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static ClassB *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [ClassA sharedInstance];  // deadlock, will be crash
    }
    return self;
}
```